# Foreground service still alive even though its process dies in a crash

Tags: android, android-lifecycle

I have a Service running in the foreground, and an Activity that interacts with it. If the Activity crashes, Android kills the entire process, including the foreground Service and its associated Threads.

However, the ongoing notification provided by the Service does not go away, and upon closer inspection, Android's task manager reveals that the Service itself is still running.

How can I kill the foreground Service in this circumstance?

Answer (score 0):

Have you override onStartCommand method of the Service? What value is it returning? If not, try to override it and return START_NOT_STICKY from it.

**START_STICKY:** If this service's process is killed while it is started, then leave it in the started state but don't retain this delivered intent. Later the system will try to re-create the service.

**START_NOT_STICKY:** If this service's process is killed while it is started, and there are no new start intents to deliver to it, then take the service out of the started state and don't recreate.

Not sure, as I have never worked on foreground services, but this might be the reason.

Comment: See my comment on the above answer; I did not think this was the issue, but just for extra peace of mind, I tried replicating the crash having started the service with a START_NOT_STICKY return value, and the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the service is not running it its own process...

Also can you confirm whether the service is getting restarted..If its getting restarted-it is because you are returning START_STICKY from onStartCommand()

Comment: The Service is not running in its own process. I do return START_STICKY from onStartCommand(), but if the process is getting restarted, onStartCommand() would receive a null intent. I check for this case and output to the log when it happens; it isn't happening.